# how to distribute the point in each category

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data is like this

```
df<- structure(list(team_3_F = c("browingal ", "newyorkish", "site", 
"team ", "browingal ", "newyorkish", "site", "team "), name = c("AAA_US", 
"AAA_US", "AAA_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "BBB_US", "BBB_US", "BBB_US"
), value = c(1L, 105L, 0L, 88L, 12L, 0L, 8L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

if I plot it like this, it does not show how many numbers belong to AAA_US and how many to BBB_US

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=team_3_F, y=value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

the same with this too

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=team_3_F, y=value)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',stackratio=1.5, dotsize=1.2)
```

This seems to be a better option and what I want

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name))
```

but as soon as I add the geom_point with value, it gives error

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name)) +
  geom_point(df$value)
```

Looking to have something like this
[image]

Comment: You have two categorical variables and one numeric variable. You want to have the two categorial variables on the axis? Then what is the scale of the numerical variable? Consider drawing a sketch of what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @stomper
I just draw something above as an example

Comment: @Ben
it is the same pattern I want but it does not reflect the numbers, for instance look at newyorkish and BBB-US, it should be 0 but your method makes it few points

Answer (score 0):

Example dataset doesn't really support what you are trying to do as only one value for each pair.  I've used jitter since it seems you have a larger dataset. This will spread the points out so they don't overlap.

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = team_3_F, y = name)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = value), color = "red", position = "jitter")
```

Comment: look at above, I just showed an example